# Flow direction outputs (ArcGIS Pro: Hydrology Tools) returning 255 values rather than 8 (D8 settings)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dem, mosaic, flow-direction

I am working with 10-meter resolution digital elevation models to produce flow direction raster images to be used ultimately for the watershed tool in ArcGIS Pro. When I use one DEM at a time, things go smooth and I end up with flow direction raster with 8 values representing 8 possible directions. However, some of my watersheds are on the edges of DEMs, so I have to combine them to capture the data needed in the tool.

Below is an example of a flow direction output that turned out correctly (on right) and one that did not (left). I have been combining rasters with the mosaic to new raster tool when needed, and these combined raster files have worked for producing flow direction products like the one on the right. For whatever reason, it is now not working for this group of rasters. Is anyone aware of why this may be happening or a workaround/fix?

[image]

Comment: Environment spatial extent is first thing to check

Comment: I am unsure what 'Environment spatial extent' refers to. A simple google search did not return anything I was able to go off of.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-extent.htm

Comment: Workflow would be to mosaic raw dem into single dem then fill sinks then compute flow direction.

Comment: FelixP, I saw this but do not understand how this would aid me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: hornbydd, I believe this is what I have expressed already. Is there a step I seem to be missing in this workflow?